# how to add regular expression for a string which is not start with special character

Tags: python

How to write a regular expression for a string that does not start with special character, the special 
the character can be anywhere in the string except as a first letter.

I want these characters should not be at starting :
    !@#$%^&*()_-+=\|][}{;:'".<,>/?~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following REGEX : `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9])(.*)`

Explaination:

1. `(?: )` - Not capturing group which means this will not be captured or this group will be ignored.
2. `(.*)` - Capturing group, will match with any  string of any length including special characters.
3. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` - This will match to any non alphabetical character or numerical number, and hence will match to Special characters only.

Comment: It is matching the whole string, but I want to match the first letter of the string.

Comment: You can use: ([^a-zA-Z0-9])(?:.*)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this is your string

This is @n apple

regex for the above string

```
(r'^[A-Z]*/[^0-9])
```

Comment: u need a regex for string tat doesn't start with special charactr. rit?